# Backup and Restore realm.io database

Tags: ios, objective-c, database, swift, realm

I need to backup my default [realm.io](http://realm.io/) database and restore it from Dropbox. I'm using the [Dropbox-iOS-SDK](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/core/sdks/osx) to upload and download it. When I tried to replace the current database file (Ex. default.realm) with the backup, the [RLMRealm](http://realm.io/docs/cocoa/0.91.1/api/Classes/RLMRealm.html#//api/name/defaultRealm) object was on the cache and I'm not able to clear that cache so I can't create a new instance of the Database.

Can I reload the RLMRealm object?

Here is the code:

```
    func reloadDB(fromPath: String) {
        let defaultParentPath = RLMRealm.defaultRealmPath().stringByDeletingLastPathComponent
        let dbPath = defaultParentPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm")
        let dbLockPath = defaultParentPath.stringByAppendingPathComponent("db.realm.lock")

        NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(dbPath, error: nil)
        NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(dbLockPath, error: nil)

        NSFileManager.defaultManager().copyItemAtPath(fromPath, toPath: dbPath, error: nil)

        self.db = RLMRealm(path: dbPath, readOnly: false, error: nil)

        NSFileManager.defaultManager().removeItemAtPath(fromPath, error: nil)
    }
```

What is the best way to backup a Realm.io database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Backing up and restoring a Realm file from dropbox should work just fine, since the database is just a file. However, you must make sure you don't have any references to the existing realm before deleting it.

Comment: should I delete the previous reference and then replace the file and create a new instance? How should I delete the reference? just set to nil?

Comment: It doesn't working. I set `self.db = nil` before replace **db.realm** and it doesn't work

Comment: be aware that any RLMObjects, RLMResults, or RLMArrays you have will also hold a strong reference to the realm

Comment: Great!! I was forgetting one reference